# Moving Polygons with snap from edge to edge using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-desktop, editing, snapping

I have such a basic question, but can't find any solution. I have some hundred rectangular Polygons and want to move them to other, already existing Polygons. The borders of these polygons should MATCH each other, so I need a snapping option.

If I try to use ArcGIS Desktop and activate the snapping, it only snaps the center point (black circle in the pic) to the borderline of existing parcels (left red line in the pic).

However, I want that the EDGES (both red lines in the pic) snap to each other. After hours of trying and searching, I can't find any solution.

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you have to move the selection anchor first:

- use edit tool and hold down the CTRL key
- drag selection anchor to the corner of your borderline

More information in [ArcGIS Help](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/by_dragging_and_snapping_to_another_feature/001t0000007z000000/).

[image]